# Getting incorrect result for Angular Momentum Density

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

[image]

I am finding the answer $\dfrac{-\mu_0 Q.m}{16\pi^2 \cdot r^5}\sin(\theta)$ direction to $\theta$ but the answer is $ r^4$. Where does the $r$ come from?

Comment: Lol where’s the question

Comment: This is not my solution. I find the same mostly. Only difference is ı found r^5 instead of r^4

Answer (score 0):

There is an $\vec r$ factor in the front of the first big expression and $\vec r=\color{red}{r}\hat r$.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't copied your answer, your answer only showed to me after I clicked "post your answer" due to page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply forgetting that the first $\vec{r}$ and putting $\hat{r}$ in it's place.
Remenber: $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}$ and $\hat{r}=\dfrac{\vec{r}}{r}$.

A simple dimensional analysis shows that it`s $\dfrac{1}{r^4}$ the correct proportionality.

Just look the first line. Since $\hat{r}$ is dimensionless and $[\vec{r}]=[r]=$meter
([X]= dimension of X) we have one $r$ at the numerator and $r^5$ in the denominator.
This naturally can only possibly lead you to $\dfrac{1}{r^4}$.